Keycloak setting custom theme for password reset throws error
I am using custom theme for my keycloak reset password functionality. Here is how i approached

Created a folder in the path /opt/keycloak/themes which is named as myTheme

Under the myTheme folder i have created an email folder

Inside email folder i have messages folder and theme.properties files

The theme.properties file has content -
parent=base
import=common/keycloakb

Inside the messages folder i have messages_en.properties file which has content
passwordResetSubject=My Custom password recovery
since i only wish to update the email Subject


But when i execute this, i get an error

KC-SERVICES0026: Failed to send password reset email:
org.keycloak.email.EmailException: Failed to template email
Caused by: org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerException: Failed to process
template text/password-reset.ftl


The only mistake I can identify from the information that you provided is a typo in your theme.properties file.
Your text reads:
parent=base
import=common/keycloakb

Note that it should read (without the b after keycloak):
parent=base
import=common/keycloak


I recreated your example by following the guides here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#creating-a-theme
And came up with the following structure:
themes/
- mytheme/
   - email/
     - theme.properties
     - messages/
       - messages_en.properties

Contents of theme.properties:
parent=base
import=common/keycloak

Contents of messages_en.properties
passwordResetSubject=My password recovery

Then to reproduce the example:

Start keycloak with args --spi-theme-static-max-age=-1 --spi-theme-cache-themes=false --spi-theme-cache-templates=false as outlined in the docs to prevent any caching of themes
Enable "Forgot Password" in Realm settings > Login
Created a test user with an email address
Triggered forgot password for that test user

As expected, I received an email with my customized subject.
